# Does this function have a name?

Tags: measure-theory

The following function came up when I was working on a problem and I want to know if there is anything known about it. Do you know if this has a name?

$p_{E}(x) := \lambda(\{z \in E: d(z,y) = x$ for some $y \in E\})$. Here $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure, $E$ is some measurable set in $\mathbb{R}$ and $d$ is the Euclidean distance function.

Comment: How do you know that the set in question is measurable?

Comment: I guess you mean the function. Good point. I don't know actually.

Comment: That is also a good question. But I meant the set $\{z \in E \mid d(z,y) = x \text{ for some } y\in E\}$.